# Android RTL: Differences between Arabic and Hebrew languages support

Tags: android, android-support-library, right-to-left, hebrew, arabic-support

I need to support both Arabic and Hebrew languages.
I've already added RTL support.

My question is:
Is there any differences between supporting Arabic and Hebrew languages in RTL?

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is,
Some words in Arabic might be larger than those in Hebrew, and vice versa. So the words might be appearing well in language and be clipped in the other language.

So it's better to create a separate layout for each of them in order to have the needed correct layout.